# How to show that the following function integrates to a finite value?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I am interested in showing that the following integral evaluates to some finite value. How can I do that ?

[image]

*Note: Outer integral is from $0$ to $1 $ (I forgot to type that in the outer integral for this image).*

My feeling was that the exponential part will always be decreasing since it will have form $e^{-x}, x>=0$. So, the integral will be bounded by the maximum value the exponential term, it should converge to some finite value. Is this reasoning correct ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmm note that the function integrating is a density for a random variable. So what?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type that in the image so I wrote the note

Comment: $ln\frac{p}{1-p}$ is not real if $p>1$ perhaps you are supposed to limit your integrals to the real domain of your integrand.

Comment: @WW1 Fixed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponent of $e$ is $-1$ times the ratio of two squares,
therefore it is negative or zero.
Raising $e$ to a negative power gives you a value between $0$ and $1$
and $e^0=1$.

If $0 \leq p \leq 1$ then $0 \leq 1-p \leq 1$,
so $0 \leq p^n \leq 1$ and $0 \leq (1-p)^m \leq 1$ for any $n$ and any $m$.

Similar reasoning applies to the powers of $q$ and $1-q$.

So you have a product of five numbers, each of which is between $0$ and $1$.
The product is therefore between $0$ and $1$.

Now that you know upper and lower bounds for the integrand, you can easily
find upper and lower bounds for the integral.
This is because if $f \leq g$ everywhere in a region $R$, then $\int_R f \leq \int_R g$.
If $g$ has the constant value $k$ everywhere on $R$, then

$$\int_R f \leq \int_R g = \int_R k = k \cdot \mathop{\rm Area}(R).$$

In the analysis above, I showed that if $f$ is your integrand, then
$f \leq 1$ everywhere in the region of integration ($0 \leq p \leq 1$,
$0 \leq q \leq 1$). That is, you can set $k = 1$ in the formulas above.

Comment: Perhaps my math is not strong enough, but can you explain how knowing that the integrand is between $0$ and $1$ can help me find the bounds of the integral ? Furthermore, I am interested in showing that above integral converge to some finite number. Thanks for any helpe.

Comment: In general, if $f \leq g$ everywhere in a region $R$, then $\int_R f \leq \int_R g$. I considered the case where the function $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from David K's answer and conclusions , the obvious upper bound is given by
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 p^4\,(1-p)^{29} \, q^{10}\,(1-q)^{23} \,dp\,dq$$ and more generally $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 p^a\,(1-p)^{b}\,  q^{c}\,(1-q)^{d} \,dp\,dq=\frac{\Gamma (a+1) \Gamma (b+1) \Gamma (c+1) \Gamma (d+1)}{\Gamma (a+b+2) \Gamma
   (c+d+2)}$$ provided $\Re(b)>-1\land \Re(a)>-1$.

For the case $a=4$, $b=29$, $c=10$, $d=23$, this gives $\frac{1}{4378463006860800}$

Comment: Just to clarify, the exponential term does not determine the upper bound in this case ?

Comment: Look at the very first sentence in David K's answer. I think it is clear that the exponential term is samller than 1. Then ...

Comment: Yes. If I am understanding right, so are all the other terms in the integrand. How do we specifically know that $p, 1-p, q, 1-q$ determines the where this integral is bound ?

Comment: This is a tighter bound than the one I presented. In the notation of my answer, I set $g$ to a constant $1$, but in this answer $g = p^4\,(1-p)^{29} \, q^{10}\,(1-q)^{23}$.